# Ruby: read info from keyboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-input

I've recently started learning Ruby on Rails, and I'm trying to write a program that will allow a little bit of user interaction via the keyboard.

In the past, I've mostly only used Java, so I was wondering what Ruby's equivalent to the readKeyboard method is, and how you would use it?

My program is just a simple one that will have lists of students, courses and modules, and will allow the user to register students to a course, and enlist them on modules that are run by that course.

I have a class called 'Module', which currently looks like this:

```
class Module
  # To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
  @@moduleScheme = nil

  def initialize(v)
    @val = v
  end
  # Set and get the @val object value
  def set (v)
@val = v
  end
  def get
    return @val
  end

  def addModule
    moduleName = Module.new(30)
    moduleRefNo = ran(100)
    moduleYear(4)
  end

  def addModuleToScheme
    moduleName.moduleScheme = schemeName
  end
  def removeModuleFromScheme
    moduleName.moduleScheme = nil
  end

  def queryModule

  end

end
```

With the 'queryModule' function, I want the user to be able to specify which module they want to query, by typing in the module's unique identifier. Presumably, I would use 'puts' to indicate that that's what the user is required to do? But then I don't know how I would read whatever the user types on the keyboard into the program. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby (as far as Rails goes) is server-side, so it tends not to be directly involved in the user interaction. You'd begin to handle it on the front-end (html, javascript, etc.)

As far as the logic goes, post human-interaction, you either have that done on frontend as well (Javascript), or if you really need Ruby on Rails to utilize the interactions you occasionally perform AJAX calls (or similar) to Rails sending the relevant information.

However: if the user is directly on the console, you read the input with `gets`, not `puts`; `puts` will print to the command line.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking I would use 'puts' to tell the user what they're required to do, i.e. an instruction saying, "Which module would you like to query?" Would that be right?

Ok, thanks, that's really helpful. Which would you recommend using out of AJAX or JavaScript, or is there not much difference/ advantage in using one over the other?

Comment: Well AJAX is Javascript. It's a way to use Javascript to contact your server, and deal with a partial page response (meaning the whole page doesn't reload, you update a small part of it, like when sites have autocomplete on their searches). So the choice between the two would be whether you can do it all on Javascript (faster) or  your server needs to know what the user's typing.